# Multiple replacements on a column replacement from a replacement table

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a requirement where I have a table `REPLACE_Table`. This table would have 2 columns: one would be `Original_string` and the other would be `Replacement_String`.

I have a cursor running on `Item_master` table. For each record, in the `Item_description` column, I need to scan for the `Replace_Table/Original_string`  and replace it with `Replace_Table/replacement_string`.

For Example, if my `Replace_Table` has these 2 rows:

```
Original_string    Replacement_String
-------------------------------------- 
LO                 @@
WO                 ()
```

If my first `Item_Description` is 'HELLO WORLD', then I should get the result as 'HEL@@ ()RLD'.

I cannot use recursive `Replace` function in SQL because I do not know the number of records in my `REPLACE_Table`. I cannot use `XLATE` because it is not character to character replacement.

Only solution I have in mind is to read the `REPLACE_Table` in a loop and keep replacing `Item_Description` column value using the `REPLACE` in SQL.

Is there any other good solution?

Comment: Given the current description, I think running it in a loop would be the preferred solution.  There is one more caveat to consider though.  What is supposed to happen if part of a replacement string shows up later in the table on an original string?

Comment: I understand what you're asking, I can't understand why you'd need this.  Can you provide some actual data?  Perhaps what you need isn't what you think.

Comment: @Player1st  Yes. that is an issue.. Infact they want to change Sybols to Escape sequences so that XML parser would not have any issues. For Example, '<' should be '&#60' and '&' should be '&#38'. So here it would be an issue. For example we have Item description as ‘<Hello>’, 
After first record is read:       ‘&ltHello>’
After second record is read:     ‘&ampltHello>’  .. which is wrong...

Comment: @Player1st  .Instead, I have suggested them to use scan and replace for all these chars. myData = %SCANRPL('"' : '&quot;' : myData);
myData = %SCANRPL('''' : '&#39;' : myData);
myData = %SCANRPL('<' : '&lt;' : myData);
myData = %SCANRPL('>' : '&gt;' : myData);
myData = %SCANRPL('&' : '&amp;' : myData);
myData = %SCANRPL('%' : '&#37;' : myData);

Comment: @Charles I think You are Right.. I may not need this. Kindly read the above two comments on the issue and Probable solution and let me know Your thoughts.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you're dealing with outputting XML and you're concerned about special characters...

Personally, I'd look at using the `CDATA` section for any data which might contain special characters...

```
<name><![CDATA[Mike & Son's Auto]]></name>
```

Is handled by an XML parser just like

```
<name>Mike &amp; Son&apos;s Auto</name>
```

would be.

Also consider looking at whatever tools you might be using for web services.  Scott Klement's excellent open source [HTTP API](https://www.scottklement.com/httpapi/) includes an `http_EscapeXml()` procedure already.

Failing that, consider using the XMLTEXT() function built into Db2 for i

```
myText = 'Mike & Son''s Auto';

exec SQL
  values (XMLSERIALIZE(XMLTEXT(:myText)
                     as varchar(50)
                     excluding XMLDECLARATION
                     ))  into :myXmlText;
```

Although XMLTEXT() only converts & and < from what I can see...

Comment: Thanks Charles.. When I was trying to test out XMLTEXT, I found out something else.. I am using XMLFOREST to create the XML..  I made my Item Description as %"<>&'    Now when I ran the query, it became%"&lt;&gt;&amp;'   . So XML function already converted <,> and &.